# Validiation Class [$this->firstname, ...] are not working

Tags: php, forms

So i'm having an issue using the `$this->firstname`, `$this->lastname`, and so on

```
class Validation
    {
        private $minLength = 2;
        private $maxLength = 25;

        public function firstnameLength($firstname)
        {
            $firstnameLength = strlen($this->firstname);

            if ($firstnameLength < $this->minLength){
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Your firstname is to short!</div>";
            }
            elseif ($firstnameLength > $this->maxLength) {
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Your firstname is to long!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function firstnameNoSpace($firstname)
        {
            return preg_replace("[ ]", "", $this->firstname);
        }

        public function lastnameLength($lastname)
        {
            $lastnameLength = strlen($this->lastname);

            if ($lastnameLength < $this->minLength){
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Your lastname is to short!</div>";
            }
            elseif ($lastnameLength > $this->maxLength) {
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Your lastname is to long!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function lastnameNoSpace($lastname)
        {
            return preg_replace("[ ]", "", $this->lastname);
        }

        public function zipcodeOnlyNumbers($zipcode)
        {
            if (!is_numeric($this->zipcode)) {
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Only numeric zipcodes allowed!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function cityNoNumbers($city)
        {
            if (preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $this->city)){
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> No numbers allowed in cities!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function streetNoNumbers($street)
        {
            if (preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $this->street)){
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> No numbers allowed in streets!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function usernameNoSpace($username)
        {
           if (preg_replace("[ ]", "", $this->username)){
               return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> No spaces allowed in username!</div>";
           }
        }

        public function usernameUnique($username)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT username FROM log_reg WHERE username = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($this->username) ."'";
            if ($sql) {
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><strong>Danger!</strong> Username is already taken!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function emailCheck($email)
        {
            if (!filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><strong>Danger!</strong> Email is not valid!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function passwordNoSpace($password)
        {
            if (preg_replace("[ ]", "", $this->password)) {
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><strong>Danger!</strong> No spaces allowed in password!</div>";
            }
        }

        public function passwordCheck($password)
        {
            if (!preg_match( '/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $this->password)){
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><strong>Danger!</strong> Your password must have at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 number!</div>";
            }

            if( strlen( $this->password) < 8)
            {
                return "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><strong>Danger!</strong> Your password must have at least 8 characters!</div>";
            }
        }
    }
```

I think i have to define a variable like `$firstname = $this->firstname` inside the function to call,

```
public function firstnameLength($firstname)
    {
        $firstname = $this->firstname;
        $firstnameLength = strlen($this->firstname);
```

but i get 2 error: 
1. `unused local variable`
2. `variable is not defined`

Comment: Do you understand what `$firstname = $this->firstname;` means?

Comment: Your class doesn't have any instance properties named `$firstname` or `$lastname`.

Comment: You define `$firstname`, but never use it. You're using `$this->firstname` to define it, and also in the second call. You can omit the first line entirely.

Comment: I'm gonna guess you have a background in a language with reverse assignments?

Comment: Change $this->firstname to $firstname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use static methods. You dont have to create instance of Validation for simple string lenght checking.

```
class Validation {
    const minLength = 2;
    const maxLength = 25;

    public static function firstnameLength ($firstname) {
        if (strlen($firstname) < self::minLength){
            return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Your firstname is to short!</div>";
        else if ($firstnameLength > self::maxLength)
            return "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Your firstname is to long!</div>";
    }
}
```

You get output by static call

```
$output = Validation::firstnameLength ("SomeFirstName");
```